# Stanford NLP/Petrarch: Discarding sentence

Tags: python, nlp, stanford-nlp

I am seeking to parse a set of news stories with *Petrarch*. According to its  [official document](http://petrarch.readthedocs.org/en/latest/inputs.html):

> The main input format for PETRARCH is an XML document with each entry
>   in the document a sentence or story to be parsed. The inputs can be
>   either individual sentences or entire stories. Additionally, the input
>   can contain pre-parsed information from StanfordNLP or just the plain
>   text with the Stanford parse left up to TABARI. Whether the input is
>   parsed or not is indicated using the -P flag in the PETRARCH
>   command-line arguments.

In other words, Petrarch uses StanfordNLP as a part of its parsing tool.

My news documents are all in one txt file without XML structure (so, no sentence attribute, id, but has date). But I want to try out with a sample text to see if this works, in which case I will reprogram those texts into corresponding format. Below is the sample:

```
<document>
<Sentences>

<Sentence sentence = "Boolean" id = "1" date = "20151026">
    <Text>China, Japan and South Korea will hold a summit in South Korea when Chinese Premier Li Keqiang visits.</Text> 
</Sentence>
<Sentence sentence = "Boolean" id = "2" date = "20151027">
    <Text>It is the first China-Japan-South Korea meeting since they were discontinued in 2012 amid tension dating back to World War Two.</Text>    
</Sentence>
<Sentence sentence = "Boolean" id = "3" date = "20151027">
    <Text>Marry has a happy life.</Text>    
</Sentence>

</Sentences>
</document>
```

The format is accept by Petrarch and the program runs without error, but there is no output. Below is my python code:

```
cd 
virtualenv venv
source venv/bin/activate
petrarch parse -i reuter1025.xml -o output.txt
```

And below is the log I copied from the Terminal:

```
(venv)d-172-26-7-114:~ Carl$ petrarch parse -i reuter1025.xml -o output.txt

new_actor_length = 0
stop_on_error = False
write_actor_root = False
write_actor_text = False
require_dyad = True
code-by-sentence True
pause_by_sentence False
pause_by_story False
Comma-delimited clause elimination:
Initial : deactivated
Internal: min = 2    max = 8
Terminal: min = 2    max = 8
Verb dictionary: CAMEO.verbpatterns.150430.txt
Actor dictionaries: [u'Phoenix.Countries.actors.txt', u'Phoenix.International.actors.txt', u'Phoenix.MilNonState.actors.txt']
Agent dictionary: Phoenix.agents.txt
Discard dictionary: Phoenix.discards.txt
Issues dictionary: Phoenix.IssueCoding.txt

Setting up StanfordNLP. The program isn't dead. Promise.
Stanford setup complete. Starting parse of 3 stories...
Done with StanfordNLP parse...

Discard sentence:   CHINA FIRST 2012
Discard sentence:   CHINA FIRST 2012
Summary:
Stories read: 0    Sentences coded: 0   Events generated: 0
Discards:  Sentence 2   Story 0   Sentences without events: 0
Coding time: 5.003469944
Finished
```

The problem appears to be that StanfordNLP disregards all of my sentences. For those of you with experience, is there anything wrong with my original format? I would really like to make this work and any thoughts will be appreciated!

Comment: I can't help with what's wrong, but it would surprise me if this is CoreNLP discarding sentences. In part, I haven't seen any such error message out of CoreNLP, and in part because CoreNLP is not in the habit of discarding sentences. The notable exception being that the parser can have a max length set, and then it will not parse longer sentences. Otherwise, perhaps the CoreNLP models did not load?

Comment: Thanks Gabor, it's good to know that CoreNLP does not typically do this. I will take a closer look at Petrarch in this case then...